# As a general rule, how can I find more information about a PowerShell object?

Tags: powershell

I found the following code while researching how I can seeing the status of a computer's Windows Update's check:

```
$UpdateSession = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
$UpdateSearcher = $UpdateSession.CreateupdateSearcher()
$Updates = @($UpdateSearcher.Search("IsHidden=0 and IsInstalled=0").Updates)
$Updates | Select-Object Title
```

This code doesn't meet my needs as it is, but I feel that it might be powerful enough to. I got rid of the `Select-Object Title` limitation and the return had a lot of properties, namely `Type` which piqued my interest because I am hoping that `Type` might delineate between driver updates, third party updates (like Microsoft Silverlight) and true "Windows Updates", but no matter how hard I look for more information I cannot find anything.

I have searched for `"Microsoft.Updates.Session"` on google and MSDN, I can't find any source that really tells me what properties are available to it and what the enumerations mean (like Type=1 vs Type=2).

Is there a PowerShell Object reference that I should be searching or, how do I go about finding more information about a PowerShell Object when I need to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, the type `[Microsoft.Update.Session]` is not really a built-in Powershell object, but part of the [windows update agent (WUA) API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wua_sdk/searching--downloading--and-installing-updates). As such, it doesn't have any built-in help files or examples powershell can show you, but it is searcheable on the Microsoft site.

The linked MS doc has some good examples of how to use the api to do different things with windows update, and it can mostly be directly converted for use in Powershell.

I happen to have used this before, so here are some basics in powershell:

```
# Create a new update session, and search for updates
$updateObject = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
$updateObject.ClientApplicationID = "Example Client ID"
$updateSearcher = $updateObject.CreateUpdateSearcher()

# Search for updates using a simple search filter, and save the results to a variable:
$searchResults = $updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0")

# If there are updates available, download them:
if ($searchResults.Updates -and $searchResults.Updates.count -gt 0){
    $count=$searchResults.Updates.count
    Write-Output ( "Found " + $searchResults.Updates.Count + " Updates" )
    $updateDownloader = $updateObject.CreateUpdateDownloader()
    $updateDownloader.Updates = $searchResults.Updates
    Write-Output "Downloading..."
    $updateDownloader.Download()

    # Then install the updates:
    $updateInstaller = $updateObject.CreateUpdateInstaller()
    $updateInstaller.Updates = $searchResults.Updates
    Write-Output "Installing..."
    $result = $updateInstaller.Install()

    # Then output the result
    Write-Output ("Installation Result: " + $Result.ResultCode)
    Write-Output ("Reboot Required: " + $Result.RebootRequired)
}
else { Write-Output "No updates found. Exiting..." }
```

As far as searching for specific updates, you'll want to add your filters to the `$UpdateSearcher.`[Search()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/nf-wuapi-iupdatesearcher-search) method. Looks like this can have type='Software' or type='Driver' for example.

Note that the WUA API has a bug/feature that generally **requires** it to be run locally on a machine instead of started remotely, though you can get around this by creating a scheduled task that runs your script.

And finally, to actually answer your question - As a general rule, `Get-Member $MyObject` and `Get-Help $MyCommand` will help you through discovering most built-in Powershell capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to use the `Get-Member` cmdlet, like:

```
$Updates | Get-Member
```

in this case it is most likely a COM object, but it should still show you the Methods and Properties

Comment: So how do I decipher the information from `Get-Member`? The information `Type   Property 
  UpdateType Type () {get}` doesn't really tell me what `Type = 1` vs `Type = 2` means, which is (in this specific case) what I'm trying to figure out.